NumPy array size and performance differences for int8 vs bool dtype
I am trying to use numpy's nbytes attribute to examine the memory usage of arrays with different dtype. I noticed the following:
>>> np.zeros(1024, dtype='int64').nbytes / 1024    # in kB
8.0
>>> np.zeros(1024, dtype='int8').nbytes / 1024
1.0
>>> np.zeros(1024, dtype='bool').nbytes / 1024
1.0  # ?

The results of the first two lines make sense to me, since the memory usage reported (8 kB and 1 kB, resp.) is simply the sum of the memory usage of each element (8 and 1 bytes, resp.) multiplied by the number of elements (1024 in both cases). However, in the last case, I would assume that an array of bool type only requires one bit of memory per element, however in seems that it requires 8 bits per element, same as int8.
My questions:

Am I interpreting correctly the output of nbytes? If so, how should we understand the fact that a bool type does not use one bit per element?
With this in mind, is there a reason to use a bool type array over an int8?


This question came up as I am dealing with arrays of binary (0 and 1) values, and was trying to find the space efficient solution (in terms of memory, since I assume there are not differences in computation times?), which I thought would be using a bool type.

numpy.bool: "Boolean type (True or False), stored as a byte."

itemsize also gives this info

Although this is not your main question, it is possible to create binary arrays in numpy. Also, if you only do element-wise logical operations, binary arrays are faster. Because if you pack 64 bools into a single int64, you can compute the logical operations for 64 elements as a single operation.

@BigBen Thanks for the link. The information in your quote is something you can easily see in the question above. What I am asking for help is to understand why this is the case and what you should do knowing about it.

@ken I am not sure I understood you. You mean use and array of type int64 but treat each element as an 64-bit boolean. Does this have a significant performance improvement? Because it sounds like you would need to invest a lot in changing your code. And is this standard practice? (Maybe this is for a separate question...)

As a sidenote for future users, @hpaulj is right and it seems that in Numpy 2.0 nbytes is removed in favor of using itemsize.


Am I interpreting correctly the output of nbytes? If so, how should we understand the fact that a bool type does not use one bit per element?

Yes, that is correct. A bool uses the same amount of space as a int8.
The reason it is done this way is that NumPy requires that all elements of an array are addressable. On most current CPUs, you can address at most at the byte level.
If you want a more memory efficient solutions, you have a few options:

NumPy can use packbits and unpackbits to convert a boolean array into an array of 8 bit integers, where each integer represents 8 booleans.
A different library, bitarray, supports 8 booleans per byte, but it has fewer features than NumPy. (e.g. no support for multidimensional arrays.)


With this in mind, is there a reason to use a bool type array over an int8?

The two act differently in a handful of ways. If you use int8 as a boolean type, then you might see some surprising results.
For example, imagine you want to take the NOT of an array. For bool, this acts as you would expect. But for int8...
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bools = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> ints = bools.astype('int8')
>>> ~bools
array([False,  True, False])
>>> ~ints
array([-2, -1, -2], dtype=int8)

... it takes the bitwise NOT of the value, which results in all 0 or 1 values becoming -1 or -2, both of which will be interpreted as True if casted back to bool.
Or, imagine you want to take values from an array where some condition is True. If you use bool, this is interpreted as a filtering operation. If you use int8, it's interpreted as an indexing operation, and you get different results.
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> a[bools]
array([0, 2])
>>> a[ints]
array([1, 0, 1])

In general, you should use datatypes in a way which explains your intent. If you intend a boolean, you should use bool. You'll find fewer surprises in NumPy that way.

Great explanation for the first question, and thanks for the links. On the second question, I am fairly well-aware of the cases where the behavior of bool and int types differs or is the same. My question was more along the lines of: in the cases where it is the same (e.g. when using or, and and xor ^ operations) is there a reason to use one over the other (e.g. for performance).
